# Bash Script 'noname' attachments gmail when using uuencode and mailx?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, gmail, ubuntu-18.04

I need to encrypt and send files through scripts. When I use uuencode to send an email, I always get a noname file with myfile?

```
`\#!/bin/sh 

TEMP_FILE1=my_file.csv 
TEMP_FILE2=my_file.csv.zip 
TEMP_FILE3=text_body.txt 
Command 
cd /part_file 
zip -P passw0rd my_file.csv.zip my_file.csv 
to="myemail@gmail.com" 
(uuencode $TEMP_FILE2 $TEMP_FILE2 ; cat "$TEMP_FILE3" ) | mailx -s 'Subject' -r "myemail@gmail.com" "$to"`
```

Please review my script and help find a solution.

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it.

i stop using uuencode and fixed mailx -mime

Comment: Indeed, don't use `uuencode` unless you specifically need to communicate with the 1980s.